# Создание inline-кнопки с Web App (Python, Aiogram)

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

Каким образом можно по команде отправить пользователю текст с прикреплённой inline-кнопкой, по нажатию на которую, будет открываться Telegram Web App с ссылкой на нужный мне сайт?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton, WebAppInfo

ikb_donate = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1,
                                inline_keyboard=[
                                    [
                                        InlineKeyboardButton(text='Донат', web_app=WebAppInfo(url=f'https://ya.ru/'))
                                    ]
                                ])
```

Comment: похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите